# What to do with my visa application - Indian passport

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, damaged-passports

My wife and I applied for Switzerland visas.  My wife's passport was slightly damaged. No pages were torn, no pages missing, all the details and previous visa visible clearly - only in one area lower down in the middle the binding of the passport could be seen.

While applying for our visas, the officer at VFS told me that my wife's visa could be rejected because of the damage. They made us sign an affidavit for the same and told us that 99 percent - visa will be rejected for both of us!

We took that 1 percent shot and applied for the visas anyway. Most likely, the visa will be rejected, given the officer's confidence.

What shall we do? Anyone with similar experience before? No visa date before 20th June for visa application and for passport renewal (15th June) in Tatkal. Our holiday was planned for 4th - 18th July 2023

Comment: You’ve submitted your application. There’s nothing you can do other than wait for a decision.

Comment: You are right ! My worry is even if I get visa - I will be in doubt - if they will let my wife board the flight because of that binding issue

Answer (score 1):

My father's Canada visa was rejected in 2009 due to damaged passport, the lamination of his passport had peeled off a bit, that time we could submit application for reconsideration to Canadian embassy, we did that and they still denied. Embassies are very careful about damaged passports and can reject visa on that basis.

We applied for Canada visitor visa later in 2014, got the visa, did not face any problems.